# Is it possible for the WixToolset to create an FTP site

Tags: wix

The WixToolset has an extension for creating websites, IIsExtension. But, I can't seem to find anything for creating an FTP.

Any suggestions, or does the creation just need to be done manually?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but it'll take custom actions.  The WiX IIS extension doesn't support this.